# Angular extract data from JSON corresponding to Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

Below is the JSON i received from server.
Now i am having variable `public checkId: any = 54`

How to extract data corresponding to `ID = 54` from below JSON ??

I want to extract below that is mentioned against KEY `54`

```
"Increase Again": true,
 "Decrease Previous" : true,
 "Like" : true,
 "Dislike" : true,
 "Old Again" : false,
 "Others" : true
```

Below is the JSON from which i have to extract above data

```
{
"27" : { 
 "Increase": true,
 "Decrease" : true,
 "Like" : true,
 "Dislike" : true,
 "Old" : false,
 "Others" : true
},
"54" : { 
 "Increase Again": true,
 "Decrease Previous" : true,
 "Like" : true,
 "Dislike" : true,
 "Old Again" : false,
 "Others" : true
},
"104" : { 
 "Increase Previous": true,
 "Decrease Prior" : true,
 "Like" : true,
 "Dislike" : true,
 "Old" : false,
 "Others Check" : true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance ...

#Edit - The key are not simply 1,2,3 they are specific Id `53,54,55` also it can `100, 108, 4657`

Comment: Since the IDs are the keys you could simply do `response[this.checkId]` assuming the object from the API is assigned to `response` variable.

Comment: @MichaelD - i have  made Edit to the response the Key are not 1,2,3 it can be any number. In that case will your soln work ??

Comment: I don't see why not. There is no difference b/n 2 or 54 or any other number from the app's perspective. It will return a valid object as long that property is available. If it isn't available it'll return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the specific element by passing the checkId in your response, For instance I'm assuming that you have that JSON in result variable.

You can call it in the following way

```
 let result = //Your json;
 let checkId = 2;
 result[checkId] ==> This will return 2nd object of JSON
```

Comment: i have  made Edit to the response the Key are not 1,2,3 it can be any number. In that case will your soln work ??

Comment: You are saying that you'll have dynamic keys?

Comment: yeah based on specific conditions that server will return, it can be any number and consequently i will have my variable checkID

Comment: If you have value set in checkID  variable, This method will work. But If you are unaware of value of checkID, we can loop through JSON data to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You Can get Ur Desired Value simply like this..

```js
let checkId = 2;
let data = {
    "1": {
        "Increase": true,
        "Decrease": true,
        "Like": true,
        "Dislike": true,
        "Old": false,
        "Others": true
    },
    "2": {
        "Increase Again": true,
        "Decrease Previous": true,
        "Like": true,
        "Dislike": true,
        "Old Again": false,
        "Others": true
    },
    "3": {
        "Increase Previous": true,
        "Decrease Prior": true,
        "Like": true,
        "Dislike": true,
        "Old": false,
        "Others Check": true
    }
}
let result = data[checkId]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: i have  made Edit to the response the Key are not 1,2,3 it can be any number. In that case will your soln work ??

Comment: @Rose - This will work. if you are looking to extract only keys , try below code  
 `Object.keys(this.data)`